# I would like to shuffle these variables then combine them in another function to print images to the screen

Tags: python, pygame

I'm following this tutorial and my own code is different, but I thought it would be easier for you if I'd show the original code as that is in English. So original code uses 7 colors and 5 shapes, I too have 7 colors and 5 shapes, but I have them as pictures though the original code drew the shape itself and then colored it. I made variables with shape or color name for example SQUARE = "square" RED = "red". So those uppercase variables equal to string with the name of the color or shape.

The problem is nothing is happening and the window is not responding when I run the game.

```
def getRandomizedBoard():
    # Get a list of every possible shape in every possible color.
    icons = []
    for c in (PUNANE, ROHELINE, SININE, MUST, KOLLANE, CYAN, LILLA):
        for s in (NURK, VIISNURK, RING, RUUT, SYDA):
            icons.append( (s, c) )

    # To decide how many icons to use, shuffle the list and then truncate it.
    random.shuffle(icons)
    numIconsUsed = int(COLS * ROWS / 2)
    icons = icons[:numIconsUsed] * 2 # going to need pairs of icons

    # Create the board data structure.
    board = []
    for x in range(COLS):
        columns = []
        for y in range(ROWS):
            randomIndex = random.randint(0, len(icons) - 1)
            columns.append(icons[randomIndex])
            del icons[randomIndex]
        board.append(columns)
    return board
```

Function to draw the shape that I changed to blit the images.

```
def drawShape(shape, color, boxx, boxy):
    left, top = leftTopOfBox(boxx, boxy)
    if shape == NURK:
        ekraan.blit(color+NURK+".png")
    elif shape == VIISNURK:
        ekraan.blit(color+VIISNURK+".png")
    elif shape == RING:
        ekraan.blit(color+RING+".png")
    elif shape == RUUT:
        ekraan.blit(color+RUUT+".png")
    elif shape == SYDA:
        ekraan.blit(color+SYDA+".png")
```

Here's the original:

```
# Memory
# http://inventwithpython.com
# By Al Sweigart al@inventwithpython.com

import random
import time
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

FPS = 30
WINDOWWIDTH = 640
WINDOWHEIGHT = 480
REVEALSPEED = 8
COLS = 10
ROWS = 6
BOXSIZE = 40
GAPSIZE = 10

DARKGRAY = (60, 60, 60)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
ORANGE = (255, 128, 0)
PURPLE = (255, 0, 255)
CYAN = (0, 255, 255)

BGCOLOR = DARKGRAY
BOXCOLOR = WHITE

DONUT = 1
SQUARE = 2
DIAMOND = 3
LINES = 4
OVAL = 5

def main():
    global MAINCLOCK, MAINSURF
    pygame.init()
    MAINCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    MAINSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))

    mousex = 0
    mousey = 0
    pygame.display.set_caption('Memory')

    mainBoard = getRandomizedBoard()
    revealedBoxes = generateRevealedBoxesData(False)

    firstStep = True
    firstSelection = None

    MAINSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
    startGameAnimation(mainBoard)

    # Main game loop:
    while True:
        clicked = False

        # Draw the board.
        MAINSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
        drawBoard(mainBoard, revealedBoxes)

        # Handle any events.
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                mousex, mousey = event.pos
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                mousex, mousey = event.pos
                clicked = True


        boxx, boxy = isOverBox(mousex, mousey)
        if boxx != None and boxy != None:
            # The mouse is over a box.

            highlightBox(boxx, boxy)

            if clicked and not revealedBoxes[boxx][boxy]:
                revealBoxesAnimation(mainBoard, [(boxx, boxy)], REVEALSPEED)
                #unrevealBoxesAnimation(mainBoard, [(boxx, boxy)], REVEALSPEED)
                revealedBoxes[boxx][boxy] = True

                if firstStep:
                    firstSelection = (boxx, boxy)
                    firstStep = False
                else:
                    # Check if there is a match.
                    shape1, color1 = getShapeAndColor(mainBoard, firstSelection[0], firstSelection[1])
                    shape2, color2 = getShapeAndColor(mainBoard, boxx, boxy)

                    if shape1 != shape2 or color1 != color2:
                        # Icons don't match. Unreveal both selections.
                        time.sleep(1)
                        unrevealBoxesAnimation(mainBoard, [(firstSelection[0], firstSelection[1]), (boxx, boxy)], REVEALSPEED)
                        revealedBoxes[firstSelection[0]][firstSelection[1]] = False
                        revealedBoxes[boxx][boxy] = False
                    elif hasWon(revealedBoxes):
                        gameWonAnimation(mainBoard)
                        time.sleep(2)

                        # Reset the board
                        mainBoard = getRandomizedBoard()
                        revealedBoxes = generateRevealedBoxesData(False)

                        # Show the fully unrevealed board for a second.
                        drawBoard(mainBoard, revealedBoxes)
                        pygame.display.update()
                        time.sleep(1)

                        # Replay the start game animation.
                        startGameAnimation(mainBoard)
                    firstStep = True

        # Redraw the screen and wait a clock tick.
        pygame.display.update()
        MAINCLOCK.tick(FPS)

def generateRevealedBoxesData(val):
    dataStruct = []
    for c in range(COLS):
        dataStruct.append([val] * ROWS)
    return dataStruct


def splitIntoGroupsOf(groupSize, theList):
    result = []
    for i in range(0, len(theList), groupSize):
        result.append(theList[i:i+groupSize])
    return result


def startGameAnimation(board):
    fakeRevealedBoxes = generateRevealedBoxesData(False)
    boxes = []
    for x in range(COLS):
        for y in range(ROWS):
            boxes.append( (x, y) )
    random.shuffle(boxes)

    groups = splitIntoGroupsOf(8, boxes)

    for g in groups:
        drawBoard(board, fakeRevealedBoxes)
        revealBoxesAnimation(board, g, REVEALSPEED)
        unrevealBoxesAnimation(board, g, REVEALSPEED)


def gameWonAnimation(board):
    global BGCOLOR, BOXCOLOR
    fakeRevealedBoxes = generateRevealedBoxesData(True)

    for i in range(14):
        BGCOLOR, BOXCOLOR = BOXCOLOR, BGCOLOR

        MAINSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
        drawBoard(board, fakeRevealedBoxes)
        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(0.3)


def hasWon(revealed):
    for i in revealed:
        if False in i:
            return False
    return True


def getShapeAndColor(board, boxx, boxy):
    return board[boxx][boxy][0], board[boxx][boxy][1]


def revealBoxesAnimation(board, boxes, speed):
    # Do the "box reveal" animation.
    for i in range(BOXSIZE, -speed - 1, -speed):
        for b in boxes:
            drawBoxCover(board, b, i)
        pygame.display.update()
        MAINCLOCK.tick(FPS)


def unrevealBoxesAnimation(board, boxes, speed):
    # Do the "box cover" animation.
    for i in range(0, BOXSIZE, speed):
        for b in boxes:
            drawBoxCover(board, b, i)
        pygame.display.update()
        MAINCLOCK.tick(FPS)

def drawBoxCover(board, b, coverage):
    """Both the revealBoxesAnimation() and unrevealBoxesAnimation() do the exact same thing inside their nested for loops, so instead of copying and pasting that code twice, we just put the code in its own function and call that function twice. Getting rid of duplicated code this way is often a good idea, because if we want to change the code later (say, if we find a bug in it), then we only have to change it in one place instead of multiple places. It also makes our program shorter and easier to read."""
    left, top = leftTopOfBox(b[0], b[1])
    pygame.draw.rect(MAINSURF, BGCOLOR, (left, top, BOXSIZE, BOXSIZE))
    shape, color = getShapeAndColor(board, b[0], b[1])
    drawShape(shape, color, b[0], b[1])
    if coverage > 0:
        pygame.draw.rect(MAINSURF, BOXCOLOR, (left, top, coverage, BOXSIZE))

def getRandomizedBoard():

# Memory
# http://inventwithpython.com
# By Al Sweigart al@inventwithpython.com

import random
import time
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

FPS = 30
WINDOWWIDTH = 640
WINDOWHEIGHT = 480
REVEALSPEED = 8
COLS = 10
ROWS = 6
BOXSIZE = 40
GAPSIZE = 10

DARKGRAY = (60, 60, 60)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
ORANGE = (255, 128, 0)
PURPLE = (255, 0, 255)
CYAN = (0, 255, 255)

BGCOLOR = DARKGRAY
BOXCOLOR = WHITE

DONUT = 1
SQUARE = 2
DIAMOND = 3
LINES = 4
OVAL = 5

def main():
    global MAINCLOCK, MAINSURF
    pygame.init()
    MAINCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    MAINSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))

    mousex = 0
    mousey = 0
    pygame.display.set_caption('Memory')

    mainBoard = getRandomizedBoard()
    revealedBoxes = generateRevealedBoxesData(False)

    firstStep = True
    firstSelection = None

    MAINSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
    startGameAnimation(mainBoard)

    # Main game loop:
    while True:
        clicked = False

        # Draw the board.
        MAINSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
        drawBoard(mainBoard, revealedBoxes)

        # Handle any events.
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                mousex, mousey = event.pos
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                mousex, mousey = event.pos
                clicked = True


        boxx, boxy = isOverBox(mousex, mousey)
        if boxx != None and boxy != None:
            # The mouse is over a box.

            highlightBox(boxx, boxy)

            if clicked and not revealedBoxes[boxx][boxy]:
                revealBoxesAnimation(mainBoard, [(boxx, boxy)], REVEALSPEED)
                #unrevealBoxesAnimation(mainBoard, [(boxx, boxy)], REVEALSPEED)
                revealedBoxes[boxx][boxy] = True

                if firstStep:
                    firstSelection = (boxx, boxy)
                    firstStep = False
                else:
                    # Check if there is a match.
                    shape1, color1 = getShapeAndColor(mainBoard, firstSelection[0], firstSelection[1])
                    shape2, color2 = getShapeAndColor(mainBoard, boxx, boxy)

                    if shape1 != shape2 or color1 != color2:
                        # Icons don't match. Unreveal both selections.
                        time.sleep(1)
                        unrevealBoxesAnimation(mainBoard, [(firstSelection[0], firstSelection[1]), (boxx, boxy)], REVEALSPEED)
                        revealedBoxes[firstSelection[0]][firstSelection[1]] = False
                        revealedBoxes[boxx][boxy] = False
                    elif hasWon(revealedBoxes):
                        gameWonAnimation(mainBoard)
                        time.sleep(2)

                        # Reset the board
                        mainBoard = getRandomizedBoard()
                        revealedBoxes = generateRevealedBoxesData(False)

                        # Show the fully unrevealed board for a second.
                        drawBoard(mainBoard, revealedBoxes)
                        pygame.display.update()
                        time.sleep(1)

                        # Replay the start game animation.
                        startGameAnimation(mainBoard)
                    firstStep = True

        # Redraw the screen and wait a clock tick.
        pygame.display.update()
        MAINCLOCK.tick(FPS)

def generateRevealedBoxesData(val):
    dataStruct = []
    for c in range(COLS):
        dataStruct.append([val] * ROWS)
    return dataStruct


def splitIntoGroupsOf(groupSize, theList):
    result = []
    for i in range(0, len(theList), groupSize):
        result.append(theList[i:i+groupSize])
    return result


def startGameAnimation(board):
    fakeRevealedBoxes = generateRevealedBoxesData(False)
    boxes = []
    for x in range(COLS):
        for y in range(ROWS):
            boxes.append( (x, y) )
    random.shuffle(boxes)

    groups = splitIntoGroupsOf(8, boxes)

    for g in groups:
        drawBoard(board, fakeRevealedBoxes)
        revealBoxesAnimation(board, g, REVEALSPEED)
        unrevealBoxesAnimation(board, g, REVEALSPEED)


def gameWonAnimation(board):
    global BGCOLOR, BOXCOLOR
    fakeRevealedBoxes = generateRevealedBoxesData(True)

    for i in range(14):
        BGCOLOR, BOXCOLOR = BOXCOLOR, BGCOLOR

        MAINSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
        drawBoard(board, fakeRevealedBoxes)
        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(0.3)


def hasWon(revealed):
    for i in revealed:
        if False in i:
            return False
    return True


def getShapeAndColor(board, boxx, boxy):
    return board[boxx][boxy][0], board[boxx][boxy][1]


def revealBoxesAnimation(board, boxes, speed):
    # Do the "box reveal" animation.
    for i in range(BOXSIZE, -speed - 1, -speed):
        for b in boxes:
            drawBoxCover(board, b, i)
        pygame.display.update()
        MAINCLOCK.tick(FPS)


def unrevealBoxesAnimation(board, boxes, speed):
    # Do the "box cover" animation.
    for i in range(0, BOXSIZE, speed):
        for b in boxes:
            drawBoxCover(board, b, i)
        pygame.display.update()
        MAINCLOCK.tick(FPS)

def drawBoxCover(board, b, coverage):
    """Both the revealBoxesAnimation() and unrevealBoxesAnimation() do the exact same thing inside their nested for loops, so instead of copying and pasting that code twice, we just put the code in its own function and call that function twice. Getting rid of duplicated code this way is often a good idea, because if we want to change the code later (say, if we find a bug in it), then we only have to change it in one place instead of multiple places. It also makes our program shorter and easier to read."""
    left, top = leftTopOfBox(b[0], b[1])
    pygame.draw.rect(MAINSURF, BGCOLOR, (left, top, BOXSIZE, BOXSIZE))
    shape, color = getShapeAndColor(board, b[0], b[1])
    drawShape(shape, color, b[0], b[1])
    if coverage > 0:
        pygame.draw.rect(MAINSURF, BOXCOLOR, (left, top, coverage, BOXSIZE))

def getRandomizedBoard():
    # Get a list of every possible shape in every possible color.
    icons = []
    for c in (RED, GREEN, BLUE, YELLOW, ORANGE, PURPLE, CYAN):
        for s in (DONUT, SQUARE, DIAMOND, LINES, OVAL):
            icons.append( (s, c) )

    # To decide how many icons to use, shuffle the list and then truncate it.
    random.shuffle(icons)
    numIconsUsed = int(COLS * ROWS / 2)
    icons = icons[:numIconsUsed] * 2 # going to need pairs of icons

    # Create the board data structure.
    board = []
    for x in range(COLS):
        columns = []
        for y in range(ROWS):
            randomIndex = random.randint(0, len(icons) - 1)
            columns.append(icons[randomIndex])
            del icons[randomIndex]
        board.append(columns)
    return board


def leftTopOfBox(boxx, boxy):
    # See how big the margins are for each side.
    xmargin = int((WINDOWWIDTH - (COLS * (BOXSIZE + GAPSIZE))) / 2)
    ymargin = int((WINDOWHEIGHT - (ROWS * (BOXSIZE + GAPSIZE))) / 2)
    left = boxx * (BOXSIZE + GAPSIZE) + xmargin
    top = boxy * (BOXSIZE + GAPSIZE) + ymargin
    return (left, top)


def drawBoard(board, revealed):
    for boxx in range(COLS):
        for boxy in range(ROWS):
            left, top = leftTopOfBox(boxx, boxy)
            if not revealed[boxx][boxy]:
                # Draw a covered box.
                pygame.draw.rect(MAINSURF, BOXCOLOR, (left, top, BOXSIZE, BOXSIZE))
            else:
                # Draw the icon.
                shape, color = getShapeAndColor(board, boxx, boxy)
                drawShape(shape, color, boxx, boxy)


def isOverBox(x, y):
    for boxx in range(COLS):
        for boxy in range(ROWS):
            left, top = leftTopOfBox(boxx, boxy)
            boxRect = pygame.Rect(left, top, BOXSIZE, BOXSIZE)
            if boxRect.collidepoint(x, y):
                return (boxx, boxy)
    return (None, None)


def highlightBox(boxx, boxy):
    left, top = leftTopOfBox(boxx, boxy)
    pygame.draw.rect(MAINSURF, BLUE, (left - 5, top - 5, BOXSIZE + 10, BOXSIZE + 10), 4)


def drawShape(shape, color, boxx, boxy):
    quarter = int(BOXSIZE * 0.25)
    half = int(BOXSIZE * 0.5)

    left, top = leftTopOfBox(boxx, boxy)
    if shape == DONUT:
        pygame.draw.circle(MAINSURF, color, (left + half, top + half), half - 5)
        pygame.draw.circle(MAINSURF, BGCOLOR, (left + half, top + half), quarter - 5)
    elif shape == SQUARE:
        pygame.draw.rect(MAINSURF, color, (left + 10, top + 10, BOXSIZE - 20, BOXSIZE - 20))
    elif shape == DIAMOND:
        pygame.draw.polygon(MAINSURF, color, ((left + half, top), (left + BOXSIZE, top + half), (left + half, top + BOXSIZE), (left, top + half)))
    elif shape == LINES:
        for i in range(0, BOXSIZE, 4):
            pygame.draw.line(MAINSURF, color, (left, top + i), (left + i, top))
            pygame.draw.line(MAINSURF, color, (left + i, top + BOXSIZE), (left + BOXSIZE, top + i))
    elif shape == OVAL:
        pygame.draw.ellipse(MAINSURF, color, (left, top + quarter, BOXSIZE, half))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: does your minimal pygame program work? For a program to be responsive, you need to remove events from the event queue.

Comment: Program works fine before the changes, I'll add the original gode too.

Comment: In your `drawShape` function, what is that `ekraan` surface that you are blitting to?  Are you ever blitting it back to the `MAINSURF`?

Comment: ekraan is MAINSURF there

Comment: If you're not getting any error messages, then I think your `drawShape` function is not even being called.  I don't believe the `Surface.blit` function offers any way of passing in the file name of an image.  You'll need to load those images and blit the surfaces to `ekraan`.  http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit

Comment: By loading you mean I should make a variable for each of the images? But how should I change `drawShape` function then?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue may be that you are not loading the images correctly. You are just blitting the name of the file name, while it is likely you want to send blit a pygame opened image. Here is how you would do that:

instead of

```
ekraan.blit(color+NURK+".png")
```

maybe this will work

```
ekraan.blit(pygame.image.load(color+NURK+".png").convert_alpha())          #I am assuming your shapes have transparent regions but if this is not the case you do not need the convert_alpha part, just convert() should be fine
```

This may be the problem. An alternative solution, if you are working with these shapes a lot, would be to use sprites and a renderupdates group, but that is really only practical if you are utilizing many of the features of the sprite object.

Another problem which is perhaps more likely the issue is that I don't see you updating the screen. After drawing your things on the screen, call:

```
pygame.display.update()
```

you may also display an optional argument for a specific rectangle to update the screen in, as this is useful to speed up your program by making it update only the necessary regions of your screen. However, if you do not specify any arguments, you could alternatively use

```
pygame.display.flip()
```

which does the exact same thing only it will not accept arguments, while the other one has optional arguments.